# How to change a very early commit in git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-rebase

Suppose I have a couple of commits A-G in my master-branch. Based on commit E, I created two branches `branchA` and `branchB` and based on commit F, I created a branch `branchC`. Suppose I introduced a critical mistake in commit D (on the branch master) that needs to be treated in `branchA`, `branchB` and `branchC` alike.

I know how to change commit D and resolve the error there (using `git rebase -i C`) - giving a new commit history A-B-C-D'-E'-F'-G' . However, that does not influence the history in any of my branches.  To be clear: `branchA` and `branchB` are still based on E and not on the rewritten commit E', which destroys the repository structure. That's not what I want - I rather want the complete tree, with everything after D', updated.

How can I resolve this situation? Is modifying the master branch's history the right idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a clean history, you could rebase each of your branches on top of `D'`:

```
git rebase D' branchA
git rebase D' branchB
```

In order to ensure you didn't made a mistake, you can check afterwards the difference between the branch before and after (`git diff <sha1_of_branchA_before>..branchA`).

It's may not be ideal if you already shared those branches with other people. If it's the case you might rather want to cherry-pick a patch in each of your branches instead. But the advantage is that you'll know that whenever you checkout an old commit, you won't land on a bogus one (as long as you checkout a commit accessible by branches, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. git is not designed for rewriting history. But it is designed for powerful branching and merging. If the fix is small, I suggest you introducing a new commit that repairs the program into the master branch, and then you cherry-pick that commit into the other branches where the fix is needed.